# Passing a missing optional (date) variable from one sub to another and still recognize it as missing

Tags: excel, vba, parameter-passing

I have a subroutine with optional variables, which calls a second subroutine (where the variables are declared as optional also), passing those variables . A simple test case is shown below.

```
Sub Test_Main()

    Call First_Sub

End Sub

Sub First_Sub(Optional aDate1 As Date, Optional aDate2 As Date, Optional aDate3 As Date)

    Call Second_Sub(aDate1:=aDate1, aDate2:=aDate2, aDate3:=aDate3)

End Sub


Sub Second_Sub(Optional aDate1 As Date, Optional aDate2 As Date, Optional aDate3 As Date)

    If IsMissing(aDate1) Then aDate1 = Now()
    Debug.Print aDate1

End Sub
```

In the Second_Sub, all date values turn to 0 and isMissing = false.

Since I have multiple optional parameters, how do I do this with out a bunch of if statements to account for all the combinations of what may and may not be present?

Or is the best way to set default values for each (that could not realistically occur) and check in Sub 2 if the value is the default value?

```
Sub Test_Main()

    Call First_Sub

End Sub

Sub First_Sub(Optional aDate1 As Date = -1, Optional aDate2 As Date = -1, Optional aDate3 As Date = -1)

    Call Second_Sub(aDate1:=aDate1, aDate2:=aDate2, aDate3:=aDate3)

End Sub


Sub Second_Sub(Optional aDate1 As Date = -1, Optional aDate2 As Date = -1, Optional aDate3 As Date = -1)

    If IsMissing(aDate1) Or aDate1 = -1 Then aDate1 = Now()
    Debug.Print aDate1

End Sub
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `IsMissing` only works with optional arguments declared **As Variant** (*"Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an optional Variant argument has been passed to a procedure"* (**Variant is in bold**)). You have given your arguments a default value, so even if they were declared `As Variant`, `IsMissing` would always return `False`. Just forget about `IsMissing` in this case.

Comment: @braX The default value of a *Variant* is *Empty*. I can see no reason to set it to *Nothing*. *Nothing* is used for objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this issue is to use default values in all optional parameters. This makes the code clearer and the call easier. Of course, what default value the parameters will have depends on what you expect them to have during operation. In this case I would set 0 as the default parameter because I think it fits better and is visualized as "00/01/1900"

```
Sub Test_Main()
    Call First_Sub(, , Now())
End Sub

Sub First_Sub(Optional aDate1 As Date = 0, Optional aDate2 As Date = 0, Optional aDate3 As Date = 0)
    Call Second_Sub(aDate1, aDate2, aDate3)
End Sub

Sub Second_Sub(Optional aDate1 As Date = 0, Optional aDate2 As Date = 0, Optional aDate3 As Date = 0)
    'If aDate1 = 0 Then aDate1 = Date: If aDate2 = 0 Then aDate2 = Date: If aDate3 = 0 Then aDate3 = Date
    If aDate1 = 0 Then aDate1 = Now():   If aDate2 = 0 Then aDate2 = Now():   If aDate3 = 0 Then aDate3 = Now()
    Debug.Print aDate1, aDate2, aDate3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the parameter, here `aDate3`:

```vb
Sub First_Sub(Optional aDate1 As Date, Optional aDate2 As Date, Optional aDate3 As Variant)

    If IsMissing(aDate3) Or VarType(aDate3) <> acDate Then
        Call Second_Sub(aDate1, aDate2)
    Else
        Call Second_Sub(aDate1, aDate2, aDate3)
    End If

End Sub
```